Mongodb Flutter Realm SDK - Wait for synchronization takes too long
I am new to using Mongodb and Atlas. I am using the Realm Flutter SDK and Flexible Device Sync for my app.
I have a problem where the wait for synchronization takes up to 6 minutes to complete before any data shows on my app. I don’t believe that is normal.
After authentication and opening the realm, and creating subscription for collections I want to write to, which happens really fast, the wait for sync take 2-7 minutes to complete. Here are sample code:
Future openRealm() async {
    var connected = await hasConnection();
  
    if (connected) {
      try {
       //Open the realm using the user credentials and schema configurations
        realm = await Realm.open(
          realmConfig,
        );
        //create or update the subscription for  collections that will be written to
        realm.subscriptions.update((mutableSubscriptions) {
          mutableSubscriptions.add(
              realm.query<Product>('userId == \$0', [login.userId]),
              name: 'ProductSubscription',
              update: true);
        // other collections...
        });
        await realm.subscriptions.waitForSynchronization();
        await realm.syncSession.waitForDownload();
      } catch (e) {
        print('$e');
      }
    } else {
      realm = Realm(realmConfig);
    }
  }

I have tried to use either wait for sync or wait for download, instead of both, to see if it reduces the time but it’s the same thing.
Please any suggestions or advice to reduce the time it takes?

Can you indicate where in your code the delay is? Is it here realm = await Realm.open?

It delays on wait for synchronization and wait for download.

So there is NO delay here realm = await Realm.open and you've verified that? If so, this sounds like an environmental issue - perhaps internet connectivity or something else in the app causing a delay. Once of our datasets is quite large and we are not encountering delays anywhere near that long. I would be curious if you were to craft a small app that just tests that code, if it's duplicatable.

I once tested removing the wait for sync and download and used just the realm = await Realm.open() , it did delay a bit but did not fetch any data. I don’t think it is a problem with the internet connection. In your program did you have to you wait for synchronization and wait for download ?

Another thing I would like to mention is that this only happens when the app newly launches. The first login or use of the app delays like this but subsequent use is faster, 30 secs or less.

In light of todays announcement of MongoDB abandoning all Realm Sync SDK's, Authentication and terminating Sync services, a better solution may be to seek another SDK.

Unfortunately so. Thanks.
